# Creating an excel file that will read file names using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS to move files from one folder to another. For that I'm using Foreach Loop and Script Task. Now I want to add Data Flow Task that will create an excel destination that will read all file names that are transferred to my destination folder. I used Script Component and Excel Destination for this, but I can't get the code to work.

```
Sub Main()

    Dts.Variables("FileName") = IO.Path.GetFileName(Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString())

    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

End Sub

End Class
```

With this code I'm getting an error "Validation errors occurred".

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the code you are doing in the script task?  In your script task are you passing the variables to the script task parameter box?

You can not assign a variable the way you are you need to use .Value like below.  You need to make sure it is set to read/write variable in the option box.

Not sure what/why you are trying to set a variable to the same variable value (with the FileName only), that should be a different variable name.

```
Dts.Variables("FileName").Value = IO.Path.GetFileName(Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString())
```

Also you should not need a script task to do this.  In your for each loop you there are ways to get just the filename without the path into your variable.  It is one of the options in the for each loop:  Under the Collection tab there is a "Retrieve file name" as fully qualified (full name/path) Name and Extension (which is what I think you are trying to accomplish above) or just "Name Only".

If you select Name and Extension I think that is all you will need to do?